# Standard Deviation and StandardDeviationFilter

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I found this scant description of `StandardDeviationFilter` in the documentation, implying one could use it to generate a moving standard deviation:

[image]
[image]

I've got a need for this sort of thing so it looked interesting.  I tried the following comparision:

```
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 1000];
sd1 = StandardDeviation[#] & /@ Partition[data, 50, 1];
sd2 = StandardDeviationFilter[data, 50]; 

ListLinePlot[{sd1, sd2[[-Length[sd1] ;;]]}, AspectRatio -> 0.25, ImageSize -> 600]
Length[#] & /@ {sd1, sd2}
sd1==sd2
```

which gives me the following output:

[image]

I'd have guessed that the two approaches would give me the same output.  Clearly not.

Can anyone explain what `StandardDeviationFilter` does or doesn't do and why it differs from the expected?

I may have missed something in setting up this comparison (it happens ;-), any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there is something wrong with your partitioning. I think the second argument of `StandardDeviationFilter` is the number of number of elements to take both to the right and to the left -- i.e., if the second argument is 1, the standard deviation will be computed with 3 elements.

Reducing the data set and simplifying `sd1` and `sd2` tends to confirm my interpretation.

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100];
sd1 = StandardDeviation[#] & /@ Partition[data, 3, 1, {2, 2}];
sd2 = StandardDeviationFilter[data, 1];

ListLinePlot[{sd1, sd2}, AspectRatio -> 0.25, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: You seem on the right track. Not certain how one gets to it from the documentation. Curious, with your code: Most[Rest[sd1]] == Most[Rest[sd2]] returns True, sd1==sd2 doesn't.

Comment: @Jagra, I'd tend to interpret "range $r$ neighborhood" to mean "value, and the $r$ values to its left and to its right", resulting in a window of length $2r+1$. BTW, what happens if you give `StandardDeviationFilter[]` *symbolic data* (e.g. `StandardDeviationFilter[Array[C, 10]]`)?

Comment: @Jagra. Re: `Most[Rest[sd1]] == Most[Rest[sd2]]` returns `True`, `sd1 == sd2` doesn't. You can see the difference at the beginning of the plot I posted. I would guess different padding at beginning is responsible.